# Как удалить строки по разным условиям?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Есть фрейм данных и мне нужно удалить из него строки, в которых значение столбца `А` более 50. Эта операция успешно выполняется кодом:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[256, 4, 24, 51], [24, 25, 34, 200], [300, 12, 45, 11],
                   [34, 19, 2, 34], [75, 76, 19, 11], [42, 89, 29, 101], [54, 104, 11, 12]])
df.rename({0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
df_without_noise = df.drop(np.where(df['A'] > 250)[0])
```

и получается

```
    A    B   C    D
1  24   25  34  200
3  34   19   2   34
4  75   76  19   11
5  42   89  29  101
6  54  104  11   12
```

Потом нужно удалить строки, в которых значения столбца `В` более 50. Я повторяю операцию, аналогичную первому удалению строк:

```
df_without_noise = df_without_noise.drop(np.where(df_without_noise['В'] > 50)[0])
```

но выводит ошибку:

> KeyError: '[2] not found in axis'

При этом, в столбце `В` присутствуют значения более 50.

Как удалить строки с ними?

Должно получиться:

```
    A    B   C    D
1  24   25  34  200
3  34   19   2   34
```

Comment: необходим [mcve]

Comment: Обновил код с датафреймом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А зачем так сложно, через `numpy`, когда можно прямо через `pandas` отфильтровать по условиям:

```
df_without_noise = df.loc[(df['A'] <= 250) & (df['B'] <= 50)]
```

А что касается ошибки в вашем коде - по умолчанию `drop` считает, что вы передали ему на вход индексы, при этом `np.where` возвращает абсолютные позиции элементов, а не индексы. Некоторые индексы в датафрейме у вас после предыдущего `drop` отсутствуют и идут не подряд, поэтому и выходит ошибка. В любом случае, лучше не смешивать библиотеки без нужды и пользоваться встроенными средствами `pandas`, раз уж вы с ней работаете.

Answer (score 5):

Также можно воспользоваться методом [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df_without_noise = df.query("A <= 250 and B <= 50")
```

результат:

```
In [28]: df_without_noise
Out[28]:
    A   B   C    D
1  24  25  34  200
3  34  19   2   34
```